# Cant type in material ui Textfield (react)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, textfield, edit

I have a simple login dialog in my react app, whose code is as-
i am calling this function within a Modal component.

```
import Jenkins_logo from "images/Jenkins_logo.svg";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';

export default function JenkinsLogin(props) {

    console.log("in login " )
    console.log(props)

    var jenkinsUsername = sessionStorage.getItem("jenkins-Username");
    var jenkinsPassword = sessionStorage.getItem("jenkins-Password");

    const handleChangeUsername = (props) => {
        sessionStorage.setItem("jenkins-Username", props.target.value);

    };
    const handleChangePassword = (props) => {
        sessionStorage.setItem("jenkins-Password", props.target.value);
    };
   
return (
            <div className="jenkins_paper" >
                    <img src={Jenkins_logo} className="jenkins_img" />
                <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
                    Sign in
              </Typography>
                    <TextField
                        variant="outlined"
                        margin="normal"
                        required
                        fullWidth
                        id="Username"
                        label="Username "
                        name="Username"
                        autoComplete="Username"
                        defaultValue={jenkinsUsername}
                        autoFocus
                        onChange={handleChangeUsername}
                    />
                    <TextField
                        variant="outlined"
                        margin="normal"
                        required
                        fullWidth
                        name="password"
                        label="Password"
                        type="password"
                        defaultValue={jenkinsPassword}
                        id="password"
                        autoComplete="current-password"
                        onChange={handleChangePassword}
                    />
            
        </div>
    )
}
```

but it does not let me edit, its sort of greyed out and wont let me click on it. below image shows.
can anyone help with what am i doing wrong.

[cannot edit image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99rCF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ciao, there are some problems in your code. Let me explain better what I mean.

When you use reactjs, write lines code directly in component body is always discouraged. Much better use the function provided by reactjs.

For example, if you want to manage var in reactjs component, better use component `state` by defining it in component `constructor` like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      jenkinsUsername: "",
      jenkinsPassword: ""
    };
    console.log("in login ");
    console.log(props);
  }
```

Now, lets say you want to load from `sessionStorage` `jenkinsUsername` and `jenkinsPassword` previously edited. You could use a function that reactjs fires one time on component load: `componentDidMount` in this way:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      jenkinsUsername: sessionStorage.getItem("jenkins-Username"),
      jenkinsPassword: sessionStorage.getItem("jenkins-Password")
    });
  }
```

Note:  `this.setState` is another function provided by reactjs to set the `state` we previously defined.

Now lets define 2 handlers to set `jenkinsUsername` and `jenkinsPassword` state and to save new values in `sessionStorage`.

```
  handleChangeUsername = (props) => {
    sessionStorage.setItem("jenkins-Username", props.target.value);
    this.setState({
      jenkinsUsername: props.target.value
    });
  };
  handleChangePassword = (props) => {
    sessionStorage.setItem("jenkins-Password", props.target.value);
    this.setState({
      jenkinsPassword: props.target.value
    });
  };
```

And finally the render function to show/edit `jenkinsUsername` and `jenkinsPassword`:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="jenkins_paper">
        <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
          Sign in
        </Typography>
        <TextField
          variant="outlined"
          margin="normal"
          required
          fullWidth
          id="Username"
          label="Username "
          name="Username"
          autoComplete="Username"
          defaultValue={this.state.jenkinsUsername}
          value={this.state.jenkinsUsername}  //current value for TextBox
          autoFocus
          onChange={this.handleChangeUsername} //handle to manage TextField value (note the **this**)
        />
        <TextField
          variant="outlined"
          margin="normal"
          required
          fullWidth
          name="password"
          label="Password"
          type="password"
          defaultValue={this.state.jenkinsPassword}
          value={this.state.jenkinsPassword}
          id="password"
          autoComplete="current-password"
          onChange={this.handleChangePassword}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

This is the correct way to work with reactjs.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-textfield-forked-hxpo2?file=/src/index.js) a codesanfbox example. Edit your values and try to reload the page: you will see previous data coming from `sessionStorage`.

Comment: I am new to this. Thank you for the detailed explanation Giovanni. Appreciate it. People like you make the world a better place :)

Comment: Glad to help you. I also was in your situation some time ago and I think that spreading knowlegde is always a good idea :).  Happy coding!